# What does it mean for a Limit to be Flat?

Tags: limits, analysis

I am reading a mathematical paper where it is stated for a particular limit that 'the limit for $t \rightarrow \infty$ is flat in some integral sense'.

Could someone clarify exactly what this means?  What does it mean for the limit to be flat?  I am assuming this is meant to be some kind of statement about the strength of the convergence?

Edit: I should add that the integral in question is the following:

$\int_0^{\infty} \int_M |\text{Ric}|^2 dV dt \leq C$,

so the paper is stating that the limit as $t$ tends to infinity is flat in some integral sense and I am not clear what that means.

Edit: I contacted the author of the paper who clarified that he simply meant that there exists a sequence of metrics such that the $L^2$-norm of their Ricci curvature goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more details would help, for example a reference to the paper, but from the context it seems likely the paper is discussing convergence of Riemannian manifolds (or similar) to a limit Riemannian manifold, perhaps in the sense of Gromov-Hausdorff. Then flatness is with regard to the curvature of the limit object, and in particular an integral curvature. From the notation it looks like they are integrating a quantity associated to the Ricci curvature. That said there are some subtleties here, as if $t$ is indexing the manifolds then they are not just integrating the curvature over the limit manifold, but all the manifolds, and presumably that this integral of a non-negative quantity is finite allows us to deduce something about the quantity in the limit. (Or at least they want you to think of it as doing so, in this 'integral sense').

Comment: I have provided a link to the article if that helps https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3220

Comment: OK. I believe everything I say stands, but the time dependent Riemannian manifolds are being generated as a type of Ricci flow (with which I am not especially familiar). In particular the integral in question refers to the mass-decreasing flow defined at the bottom of page 4. Suggest starting there but from the way the paper is written you may need to check a background source for the fundamentals.

Comment: OK thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of a background source, I am using the book on the Ricci flow by Tian and Morgan, as it seems like this is the only source which is going to discuss Ricci flows in a general way with the required level of technicality.